# css @media mobile/desktop: ensuring desktop doesn't show mobile css

Tags: html, css, mobile, media

been making a mobile redesign of a site, simply via CSS.

have the following media queries serving up appropriate css for either desktop or mobile

but, the desktop will still show the mobile css (although it seems only some of the mobile css files) when browser is resized under 855

how do you ensure the desktop never loads the mobile css?

thanks

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layout.css" media="Screen and (min-device-width:855px),projection" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/nav.css" media="Screen and (min-device-width:855px),projection" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/type.css" media="Screen and (min-device-width:855px),projection" />

<link href="css/mobile.css" type="text/css" media="handheld, handheld and (max-device-width: 854px), only screen and (max-device-width: 854px), only screen and (max-width:854px)" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/mobile-nav.css" type="text/css" media="handheld, handheld and (max-device-width: 854px), only screen and (max-device-width: 854px), only screen and (max-width:854px)" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/mobile-type.css" type="text/css" media="handheld, handheld and (max-device-width: 854px), only screen and (max-device-width: 854px), only screen and (max-width:854px)" rel="stylesheet" />
```

kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following rule at the end of your mobile stylesheet media queries: `only screen and (max-width:854px)`. This applies the stylesheet when a browser is resized under 855px. If you only want the stylesheets to be applied on *devices* that are 854px or less in width, use the `max-device-width` property only.

Comment: thank you. had to use max-width in order to get android mobile to work.